# How to access two separate web servers via a Linux Gateway running IP tables

Tags: networking, iptables

I have two Ubuntu 12.04 servers. Server 1 acts as the firewall using IP tables and hosts the Proxy server. Server 2 hosts the web server.

I have an external ip address terminating on eth1 on Server 1. IPtables forwards ports 443 and 80 successfully from eth1 to eth 0 onto Server 2. The web server is accessible externally.

I have procured another external IP address that will also terminate on eth1:1 - I have set up the network to accept that. I want to accept traffic on ports 443 and 80 on the second IP address (eth1:1) and forward that traffic to another web server using another internal IP address.

I am unsure how to configure IPtables to forward the traffic from IP address 2 : 443 or 80 to the another web server.

Internal IP addresses are:

Server 1 - 192.168.1.123 Server 2 - 192.168.1.120

I have configure eth1 and eth1:1 and can access the existing web server via both IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

> https://superuser.com/questions/400867/iptables-trouble-nat-with-ip-alias-virtual-interface-not-working
>
> When you use virtual interfaces just use the option -d (destination),
>   ignoring the option -i (interface)
>
> Instead of: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 25.25.25.26 -j
>   DNAT --to-destination 172.16.2.1
>
> use: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 25.25.25.26 -j DNAT
>   --to-destination

---

The trick is to use the -d parameter in the PREROUTING chain. So in this case I used -d xxx.xx.xx.18 and for port 443 - directed it to port 4431. I set up the other servers firewall to accept 4431 and set nginx site to accept https on 4431.

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d xxx.xx.xx.17 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 191.168.1.120:80

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d xxx.xx.xx.17 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 191.168.1.120:443

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d xx.xx.xx.18 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 191.168.1.120:801

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d xxx.xx.xx.18 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 191.168.1.120:4431